# dyld: library not loaded. no such file

Tags: c, macos, cs50, dyld

```
h@Hrvojes-MacBook-Pro problemSet2 % ./hours                      
dyld[18659]: Library not loaded: libcs50-11.0.2.dylib
  Referenced from: <099E85B4-69E7-3DB9-BBCB-261540A924DC> /Users/h/CS50 Learning/2.ARRAYS/problemSet2/hours
  Reason: tried: 'libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), 'libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/h/CS50 Learning/2.ARRAYS/problemSet2/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/h/CS50 Learning/2.ARRAYS/problemSet2/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/h/CS50 Learning/2.ARRAYS/problemSet2/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      ./hours
```

I tried running a simple program I wrote and it's not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install, and/or locate, the dynamic library it is looking for: [libcs50](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50)

---

The instructions for installing on mac OS are (copied from [README.md](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/main/README.md)):

#### From Source (Linux and Mac)

1. Download the latest release from https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/releases
2. Extract `libcs50-*.*`
3. `cd libcs50-*`
4. `sudo make install`

By default, we install to `/usr/local`. If you'd like to change the installation location, run
`sudo DESTDIR=/path/to/install make install` as desired.

---

Afterwards, recompile your program (link with `-lcs50`).

If you are still having trouble, ensure you are looking for the dynamic libraries in the correct place by using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

With the default install from above, execute your program as:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./hours
```

(*If you installed with a different path, i.e., you used `DESTDIR` above, then specify that path for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.*)

Comment: I've been using this library for a few weeks now and I actually got this error when I updated my OS today. So I might need to locate it. I'm pretty new to all of this so how can I actually do it with the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to fix that little issue.
First execute the following command

```
find / -name "libcs50-11.0.2.dylib"
```

Once "find" finishes his search use the "mv" command to rename the files

```
 mv /path/to_file/"libcs50-11.0.2.dylib" /path/to_file/libcs50_11_0_2.dylib
```

Notice the underscores you can even not put them at all like this

```
mv /path/to_file/"libcs50-11.0.2.dylib" /path/to_file/libcs501102.dylib
```

As final step try to run your program again.